# Getting Facebook error 11

Tags: facebook, api, blackberry, deprecated

I am using 
 version 5.0 of BBplugin in eclipse and the FB jar lib ( FacebookBlackBerrySDK-v0.8.25.jar ) 
i get an error 
API error code :11
API Error Description : This method is deprecated
Error Message: Display=wap dialogs have have been deprecated . You can temporarily enable them by disabling the "july_2012" migration.They will stop working permanently on july 1,2012.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/FaceBook-API-error-code-11-Method-Deprecated/td-p/1671793

I checked out this link ..
But it isn't giving the solution

I tried out for july 2012 migration solution only 
i have not tried the solution  display=wap into display=touch

as i don't know where it is

i get the following error when i run it on simulator

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=191m3o&s=6

```
import com.blackberry.facebook.ApplicationSettings;
import com.blackberry.facebook.Facebook;
import com.blackberry.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.blackberry.facebook.inf.User;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;


public class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener{

    private User user;
    String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
    String APPLICATION_ID = "My App id"
    String APPLICATION_SECRET = "My Application Secret";


    String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.ALL_PERMISSIONS;
    private Facebook fb;
    private ApplicationSettings as;
    private String id="";
    private EditField ef;

    private ButtonField bf;

    public MyScreen(String id ) {

        //      this.user = user;
        this.id = id;

        ef = new EditField("Hi", " ");
        bf = new ButtonField("Publish");
        bf.setChangeListener(this);
        add(ef);
        add(bf);

    }

    private void FBPost(){

        ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
        Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);



        as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
        fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
        try {

            user = fb.getCurrentUser();
            String result = user.publishStatus(ef.getText());

            if ((result != null) && !result.trim().equals("")) {
                Dialog.inform("Publish Success.");
            } else {
                Dialog.inform("Publish Failed.");
            }
        } catch (FacebookException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Dialog.inform("Exception in myscreen");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

        if(field==bf){

            String text = ef.getText();
            FBPost();

        }

    }
}
```

Above is my code Please 
check out

Comment: @Yan: added my code ... check out

Comment: which version of SDK are you using??

Comment: @BBdev: version 5.0 of BBplugin in eclipse
and the FB jar lib  ( FacebookBlackBerrySDK-v0.8.25.jar )

Comment: Actually i found out that if i create another ID and Secret key it works and not for mine
i took a id and secret key for an app which was already tested and so it did worked ,, ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your app setting on facebook. and in Migrations disable last three options(July 2012 Breaking Changes, Include Checkins with Statuses, August 2012 Breaking Changes).Hope it will help you :)