# Unable to post link via graph API php sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can't understand the problem. I followed the tutorial at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/ .

But, I cannot post a link to the user's wall. The following is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXX',
)); 
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if($user) {
  try {
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
      array(
        'link' => 'www.example.com',
        'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
    ));
    echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

    // Give the user a logout link 
    echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
      'scope' => 'publish_stream'
    )); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {
  // No user, so print a link for the user to login
  // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_stream permission
  // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
  // need to specify it here.
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream'));
  echo 'No user...Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
}  
?>
```

I have enabled error reporting but can not display any error. The output is always:

> "Please login."

When I click the link, after the redirection from facebook, again the same message displays.

Comment: So, `$user` is not evaluating to bool true in the last `if/else` block. That's either because the method in line 8 returns false/null, or you're setting to null explicitly in line 14. Which is it? If it is the latter, what exception do you get?

Comment: The problem is that I get no exception...Despite turning error reporting on, no error is being displayed... :(

Comment: After line 7 check if you have any `$user`

Comment: I have pasted the full source code...

Comment: Replace `error_log($e);` with `echo $e->getMessage();`? It looks like you are catching the exception and then sending it to a log - at the moment you need to see it on-screen.

Comment: Now it displays "11"...Cannot understand this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515924/getting-facebook-error-11

Comment: (By the way, the help you see under the comment box says you need to use @name to notify people - it is really true! People are generally not notified of messages unless they are addressed directly, or the comment appears on their question/answer).